# LibreOffice calc: create multiple chart series from column values

Tags: libreoffice-calc

Sorry for the basic Calc question, but I'm very inexperienced with spreadsheet charts and need some help. I've tried searching for the answer but surprised that I can't find anything that answers what I would have thought was a very common data problem. I have three columns:

```
Date        | Category  | Value
-------------------------------
2022-05-16  | Cat A     | 2.3
-------------------------------
2022-05-17  | Cat A     | 3.4
-------------------------------
2022-05-15  | Cat B     | 2.1
-------------------------------
2022-05-18  | Cat B     | 5.1
```

Question is simply this - how do I create the following chart without reorganising my data into a column for each category?

[image]

I just can't figure this out. Sorry, I'm probably missing something obvious. How do I use column B to create multiple data series dynamically? The reason I don't want to reorganise my data into columns is that the data is created dynamically from an external source, and **I don't know beforehand what categories there will be or even how many categories there will be**.

Thanks so much

Comment: I, too, have looked for an answer to this, and been astonished not to find one.  Sorry to not have any solution to contribute atm.

Answer (score 0):

I've wanted to do this on several occasions, and I still haven't found a GOOD answer, so I made my own workaround.

https://github.com/Erhannis/CategorizedSpreadsheetGraphGenerator

Pipe a CSV to it and it creates an XLSX with a chart like how you want.
...Note that it expects numbers for both x and y, so I guess plain dates won't work, sorry - I usually use [unix millisecond timestamps](https://currentmillis.com/).  Feel free to mess with the code, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue which I could not resolve with LibreOffice Calc, but did solve it with [RAWGraphs](https://app.rawgraphs.io/).

1. Upload CSV
2. Select Line chart
3. Map fields as follows
4. Configure chart options and download chart

[image]
[image]